# Energy in electric field of an electron?

Tags: electrostatics, energy, electric-fields, potential-energy, calculus

I am just trying to get an intuition for the Griffiths equation no. 2.45, where work done to establish a field E is given by
Say we want to solve it for electric field due to an electron (point-charge)
\begin{gather}
                       W = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int\limits_{all \, space} E^2 d\tau  
\end{gather}
Intuitively, say we want to compute the electric field due to a point charge, say an electron, we can substitute, the electric field due to Coulombs law
\begin{gather}
E = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0\,r^2} =\frac{kq}{r^2} \quad \quad where \, k = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}
\end{gather}
But in spherical co-ordinates, this turns out to be
\begin{gather}
W = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int\limits_{all \, space} E^2 d\tau\\  
W = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} E^2 \, r^2 dr \, sin\theta \, d\theta \, d\phi
\end{gather}
Substituting above we obtain
\begin{gather}   
W =  k^2q^2 \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi}\, sin\theta \, d\theta \, \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^4} r^2 dr \\
W =  k^2q^2 \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \,\,2 \,\, 2\pi\,  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^2} dr \\
W =  2 k^2q^2 \pi \epsilon_0   \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^2}  dr
 =  A \, \left[ \frac{1}{r} \right]_\infty^0   \quad where \quad A = 2 k^2q^2 \pi \epsilon_0 
\end{gather}
But this integral is not defined at $r = 0$. How to go about this issue?
Is the problem lies in the definition of point charge. Like how to define point charge at $r = 0$. Sorry! If I made any trivial mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Search for "self energy problem of the electron". A reasonable answer can only be given in the framework of quantum electrodynamics.

Comment: But I am simply amazed at how such a simple calculation leads to so profound question which requires QED. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: @SACHLEENSINGH See section 8-6 of Feynmann's lectures on physics, he thought the problem was interesting too, just keep in mind that the stuff dates to back in the sixties.

Comment: Thanks @AlbertusMagnus really appreciate it.